# Does MPI_Irecv complete on MPI_SSend or is MPI_Wait (or other variant still needed)

Tags: mpi

I understand that calls to MPI_Irecv need to be paired with a MPI_Wait (or MPI_Test etc.; cf. [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_Irecv.3.php) to complete. However, with the code below the MPI_Ssend seems to be forcing the Irecv to complete.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  int rank = 0;
  int size = 0;

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  if (size != 2)
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);

  int send_buffer_0 = 0;
  int send_buffer_1 = 1;
  int recv_buffer_0 = -1;
  int recv_buffer_1 = -1;

  MPI_Request request;

  if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Irecv(&recv_buffer_0, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    MPI_Ssend(&send_buffer_0, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  } else {
    MPI_Irecv(&recv_buffer_1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    MPI_Ssend(&send_buffer_1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  // MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

  if (rank == 1)
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " recv'd " << recv_buffer_1 << std::endl;

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

If I change the sends to MPI_Send then the MPI_Wait is needed for the message to be received as I suspect the MPI implementation is buffering the send.

Is the MPI_Ssend call forcing the Irecv complete such that a wait or test is not needed? Is this implementation specific or expected from the standard?

Comment: I think it's coincidence. You need the `Wait` call. Also: wihtout the wait call you have a memory leak because your request object is not released. Don't do it.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, thanks. I'm a bit confused about your memory leak comment. The request object is allocated on the stack. Is MPI doing some allocation behind the scenes?

Comment: The pointer to the request is on the stack. The actual object is created in the `MPI_Iwhatever` call. That's why you pass it as `&request`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the synchronous mode:

> A send that uses the synchronous mode can be started whether or not a matching receive was posted. However, the send will complete successfully only if a matching receive is posted, and the receive operation has started to receive the message sent by the synchronous send. Thus, the completion of a synchronous send not only indicates that the send buffer can be reused, but it also indicates that the receiver has reached a certain point in its execution, namely that it has started executing the matching receive. If both sends and receives are blocking operations then the use of the synchronous mode provides synchronous communication semantics: a communication does not complete at either end before both processes rendezvous at the communication.

There is nothing here that would imply that you don't need to wait with the code you provided.